# Is ARCore running on MagicLeap One?

Tags: arcore, magic-leap

I would like to use ARCore on Magic Leap One. Is this possible?
Can someone tell me if it is supported?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, that remains to be seen, maybe with their push into mobile-phone AR they might support it. This [article](https://variety.com/2019/digital/news/magic-leap-mobile-ar-1203109944/) talks about it:

> The job listing also specifies that applicants should have experience
>   with ARKit and ARCore, the mobile AR frameworks developed by Apple and
>   Google, respectively. However, it’s not clear whether Magic Leap plans
>   to use ARKit and ARCore, or whether the company is looking to bring
>   its own AR technologies to mobile devices.
>
> This isn’t the first time Magic Leap has hinted at plans to offer some
>   cross-platform functionality for AR developers. The company’s chief
>   content officer Rio Caraeff suggested in an interview with Variety at
>   the sidelines of the company’s Leapcon developer conference last year
>   that this type of interoperability would be key to taking Magic Leap
>   out of the home, and into shared spaces.